# How to pass individual prop values to same component when using Context in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I thought with Context Hooks, one should NEVER use props.

If i am rendering the below

```
               <DBButton name={"Couchbase"} onClick={()=>setActiveDBName("Couchbase")}/>

                <DBButton name={"Cassandra"} onClick={()=>setActiveDBName("Cassandra")}/>

                <DBButton name={"MongoDB"} onClick={()=>setActiveDBName("MongoDB")}/>
```

How do I pass the "couchbase"/"cassandra"/etc names to the DBButton functional component only using Context and not through props?

Comment: Context is not a replacement for props. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. 

How can I get rid of duplication in the above components - "couchbase"/"mongodb"/etc is mentioned 2 times. Is there a way for me to avoid that?

Comment: If you can change the DBButton however you want, you can make the onClick of DBButton pass the `name` prop as an argument.